# Using 2 different rules (like a or()) for the same url in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I need to secure url so there are 2 possible ways to access:

- the client has a specific ip
- or the client needs to be logged in

So, I need to give two rule for a single URL, using something like the `or` method below:

`.antMatchers("/url/**").authenticated().or().hasIpAddress("192.bla.bla")`

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them using SPEL.

```
String expression = "hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')";
http
   .authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/home").access(expression)
```